# Cython Iterating through array and indexing still slow

Tags: python, indexing, iteration, cython

Iam currently trying to speed up an algorithm which takes an array of x,y-Coordinates,finds the specified number of points that are furthest apart from each other (based on two given start points) and returns their indices.

That is what the code looks like:
(distMat is an array that holds the distances of all points to each other, numIndices the number of points desired, and index0 and index1 the indices of two startPoints.)

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

DTYPE = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t
ctypedef np.int32_t INT32_t
ctypedef np.int64_t INT64_t


def find_furthest_indices(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] distMat, int numIndices, int index0, int index1):
    cdef int i, j
    cdef double dist, minDist, curDist
    cdef np.ndarray[INT32_t, ndim=1] selectedIndices = np.empty(numIndices, dtype=np.int32)
    cdef np.ndarray[INT32_t, ndim=1] remainingIndices = np.arange(numIndices, dtype=np.int32)

    selectedIndices[0] = index0
    selectedIndices[1] = index1
    for i in range(numIndices-2):
        minDist = 0.0
        for j in remainingIndices:
            dist = np.inf

            for k in selectedIndices[:i+1]:
                curDist = distMat[j][k]
                if curDist < dist:
                    dist = curDist

            if dist > minDist:
                minj = j
                minDist = dist

        selectedIndices[i+2] = minj
        remainingIndices = remainingIndices[remainingIndices!=minj]

    return selectedIndices
```

It works but (as also expected) is still a bit slow when handing in larger Arrays (e.g. 5000 points -> distMat is 5000x5000 and numIndices = 500). That is probably because of the nature of the algorithm ("Kennard-Stone" for those, who really want to know), but Iam wondering about the colored output from the cythonize:
[CythonizeOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l10ks.png)

It marks the following lines in dark yellow, meaning there is a lot of Python interaction to translate to C.. I don't get why these three are amongst them:

```
for j in remainingIndices:
```

```
for k in selectedIndices[:i+1]
```

and

```
curDist = distMat[j][k]
```

Can somebody shed some light on why these lines are slow in that context? I have added type definitions for the given parameters, so iterating through them and indexing should be fast??

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
for j in remainingIndices:
```

Iterating using the Python iter protocol. In Cython you're better off using range and indexing. You want something like:

```
for jidx in range(remainingIndices.shape[0]):
    j = remainingIndices[jidx]
```

---

```
for k in selectedIndices[:i+1]
```

Same as above

---

```
curDist = distMat[j][k]
```

Creates a slice of the array, then indexes into the slice (has to fall back to Python for both of these). You want

```
curDist = distMat[j, k]
```

Comment: Uuuuh, thanks for the help! That already boosted the speed by a factor of about 2 and, more importantly, I again learned a bit more! ;-)

However, the 
```
curDist = distMat[j, k]
```
piece still remains in quite dark yellow and seems to be a bottleneck. But there is probably nothing to do about it?

Comment: You might want to try the [`boundscheck` and `wraparound`](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compiler-directives) compiler directives. Make sure that you don't need the features the provide, and do think about whether these directives are helpful rather than blindly applying them to everything. Can `numIndices` come from `distMat.shape`? Or can you check the size will be in-bounds once before the loop? This would make `boundscheck` safe...

Comment: Thanks, I'll think about that.
numIndices cannot be directly derived from the distMat.shape, unfortunately. However, I could implement a quick check or assertion to make sure the index doesn't go beyond..